# C++/CX in winrt: filter specific types in Vector<ItemRenderer^>

Tags: casting, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have `Vector<ItemRenderer^>`. `ItemRenderer` is an abstract type. I want to filter all `ConcreteRenderer` and do some action with them.

What I have tried:

```
for each (auto renderer in m_parts)
    if (renderer->GetType() == ConcreteRenderer::typeid)
    {
        auto item = dynamic_cast<ConcreteRenderer^>(renderer);
        item->SetState(1);
    }
```

But `renderer` has type `VectorProxy<ItemRenderer^>` and nothing works. How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

So I used the following code:

```
for each (auto renderer in m_parts)
{
    auto item = dynamic_cast<ConcreteRenderer^>((ItemRenderer^)renderer);
    if (item != nullptr)
        item->SetState(1);
}
```

Now everything works well. Is it a common solution, or there is something else?

Comment: What does "nothing works" mean?  What have you tried?

Comment: @mydogisbox statements under if condition are never performed

Comment: @mydogisbox I have tried the code above, isn't it obvious?

Comment: Generally it's good practice to try a bunch of things before posting a question.  A summary of all the different things you tried makes answering your question a much easier job.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Comment: @mydogisbox well, I've tried something, described it and written why it does not work. btw, I did not stop looking for a solution and found it, I've updated a question with it and asked how good my solution is. and I looked at your questions, the first two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201953/convert-stdvector-to-nsarray and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440273/configure-script-in-xcode-fails-with-exit-code-1 - I can't see "try a bunch of things before posting a question" - why not follow good practice, if your are suggesting making so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've found the correct solution (for each element, dynamic_cast to the target type, and if the dynamic cast returns non-null, then the element is of the expected type).

What you were trying (`p->GetType() == Thing::typeid`) is not going to work because these expressions both return a `Platform::Type^`.  As this is a handle/pointer type, you are performing a pointer comparison (not an identity comparison).  This is basically always going to return false in your scenario.

If you want to do it by using type identities instead of casting, you can, but you should perform a string comparison of the `FullName` property on the type objects.  Eg: `if (p->GetType()->FullName == Thing::typeid->FullName)`.

However, I believe the dynamic_cast solution will have better performance characteristics in general. (Especially since if you do find the types are the same you'll have to perform that dynamic_cast anyways!)